# ajax search suggest autocomplete, server keep querying

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, autosuggest

ajax search suggest autocomplete. when i input something, ajax sends them to the server, query them and send back to client. But sometime when i input some words, ajax sends them to the server, server keep querying them. Should I set up timeout?

Answer (score 0):

I would think so. You actually need to give more background info. There is too less info to make any guesses or suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

I using workbench. So I upgraded it to newer version. It looks like its working fine